# Mysql slow.log user specific

Tags: mysql, logging, config, user-management

I use a `slow.log` logging on my MySQL server to catch bottlenecks in my scripts, but at the same time I use `phpmyadmin` on this server. My scripts and `phpmyadmin` has different MySQL user accounts and now, when I analyzing the `slow.log` file, I see a lot of spam from `phpmyadmin` queries, is it possible, to configure the MySQL to logging a slow queries only from specific users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using MySQL 5.6, you can use the performance schema, and look at the different statements summaries there.

There are summaries by account (someuser@somehost), by username alone (someuser) or by host alone (somehost).

See the following tables:

- performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name
- performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_user_by_event_name
- performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_host_by_event_name
- performance_schema.events_statements_summary_global_by_event_name

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html